# serviceWorker 'activate' and 'message' events not firing

Tags: javascript, service-worker, service-worker-events

I'm trying to use `serviceWorkers` for the first time, and even though it started well, I'm a little stuck..

Here's my very simple `service-worker.js`:

```
self.addEventListener('install', () => {
  console.log('Hello world from the Service worker')
})

self.addEventListener('activate', () => {
  console.log('Serive worker now active')
})

self.addEventListener('message', event => {
  console.log('Service worker received message ' + JSON.stringify(event))
})
```

I register for the service worker like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker
        .register('/service-worker.js')
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Service worker registration successful')
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.error('Service worker registration failed: ' + e)
        })
    }
  }, [])
```

As I load my app, I get the following logs:

```
Service worker registration successful // APP
Hello world from the Service worker // SERVICE WORKER install event
```

So, I do get the `install` event called, but not the `activate` event.

Also, when I send a message to the service worker from my app:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage({test: 'test'})
```

the `message` event on the service worker doesn't get called either...

**Is there something wrong I'm doing? Doesn't the service worker activate somehow?**

For additional context, my app uses `Next.js`, and I place the `service-worker.js` in the `public` folder in my project.

Also, on the app, if I try posting the message like this:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
  console.log(registration.active)
  registration.active.postMessage({test: 'test'})
})
```

I get logged the instance of the service worker, (I assume) meaning that the service worker is indeed active/ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ServiceWorkerRegistration.active` isn't immediately available, so the instance should be obtained with `installing` or `waiting` first. `skipWaiting()` could be used when the SW is updated/modified since last installation.

```
// main.js

navigator.serviceWorker?.register('./service-worker.js')
  .then(reg  => {
    console.log('registered', reg)
    const sw = reg.installing || reg.waiting || reg.active
    sw.postMessage({ milliseconds: Date.now() })
  })
  .catch(() => console.error('registration failed'))
```

```
// service-worker.js

self.addEventListener('install', e => {
  console.log(e.type)
  self.skipWaiting() // always activate updated SW immediately
})

self.addEventListener('activate', e => console.log(e.type))

self.addEventListener('message', e => console.log(e.type, e.data))
```

Comment: `skipWaiting()` is what fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: A bit of clarification:

from https://web.dev/service-worker-lifecycle/: "Once successfully installed, the updated worker will wait until the existing worker is controlling zero clients. (Note that clients overlap during a refresh.)" 

What that quote means is that a new version of the service worker will only activate once all the browsers on your computer no longer are on a page in the scope of the service worker. 

So if you're developing locally, you don't need skipWaiting if you close/reopen the tab viewing the page under development